# How do I replicate this .NET generated key using Python?

Tags: python, encryption, .net-3.5, encryption-symmetric

I am using the following .NET code to generate a key from a password and salt:

```cs
static byte[] GenerateKey(string password, string salt, int size)
{
    var saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, iterations);
    var key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(size);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(key)));

    return key;            
}

// Console.Writeline() shows 
// Key: tb6yBBYGdZhyFWrpWQ5cm5A1bAI5UF0KnDdom7BhVz0= 
// for password="password" and salt="salt"
```

I need to decode the encoded message using python, a language I am only slightly familiar with, using the same password and salt.  Thanks to @Topaco I now know that there is the [PBKDF2 equivalent](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/kdf.html#pbkdf2):

```py
def decrypt_file(filename, password, salt):

    key = PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, count=12345, hmac_hash_module=SHA1)

  print(f"Key: {base64.b64encode(key).decode('utf-8')}");
  # more lines redacted 
 
# print() shows
# Key: 3ohW9ctQIXoNvGnvLaKmoQTG8/jJzoFThviHXqgM9Co=
# for password="password" and salt="salt"
```

I'm having some trouble getting the same key from both implementations.  I am *not* well-versed in python's encoding and decoding; it's <s>entirely likely</s> possible that I *am* generating the same key but the `base64.b64encode(key).decode('utf-8')` line is showing me a different translation.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-6.0) implements PBKDF2, using HMAC-SHA1 and an iteration count of 1000 by default. Most major crypto libraries support PBKDF2, e.g. PyCryptodome. [Here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/protocol/kdf.html#pbkdf2) you can find an example.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco; I've edited the question to reflect my current roadblock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode the salt with UTF-16LE since [`Encoding.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=net-6.0) corresponds to UTF-16LE. The rest is fine:

```py
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Hash import SHA1
import base64

password = b'password'
salt = 'salt'.encode('utf-16le')
key = PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, count=12345, hmac_hash_module=SHA1)
print(base64.b64encode(key).decode('utf-8')) # tb6yBBYGdZhyFWrpWQ5cm5A1bAI5UF0KnDdom7BhVz0=
```

---

For completeness: If the password contains non-ASCII characters, the password in the Python code must be encoded with the more specific `'...'.encode('utf-8')`, since the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-rfc2898derivebytes-ctor(system-string-system-byte()-system-int32)) overload used in the C# code encodes the password string with UTF-8.